# MySQL DATE query returns nothing

Tags: mysql

can someone tell me why the following query returns nothing:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * from basiszins WHERE start_datum > '2016-07-02'");
    if($statement->execute()) {
        while($fetchtest = $statement->fetch()) {
            echo $fetchtest['start_datum']."<br>";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "SQL Error <br />";
        echo $statement->queryString."<br />";
        echo $statement->errorInfo()[2];
    }
```

MySQL column is of type Date. DB entries look like for example '2014-07-01'. The query returns with an equal (=) operator and matching query string but not with a larger as (>) operator.

Can someone explain to me why?.

Thank you!

Comment: Is your sample data correct? 2014 came earlier than 2016.

Comment: I´m sorry, you are right Alvaro. Had some spaghettis in my head. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample of your problem:

```
create table dates(
someDate Date
);
insert into dates (`someDate`) values ('2021-01-01'),('2019-01-01'),('2020-01-01');
```

Query

```
SELECT * from dates where someDate > '2020-01-01'
```

Result

```
2021-01-01
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38b5ab/1